# Import PyQt4.pyqtconfig does not work even if the file is there

Tags: python-2.7

My system is Ubuntu 12.10. I tried to install popplerqt4, but when I try to compile the setup.py, it gives me the error:

`import PyQt4.pyqtconfig`

`ImportError: No module named pyqtconfig`

A search like: locate pyqtconfig gives the results:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/pyqtconfig.py

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/pyqtconfig.pyc

/usr/share/pyshared/PyQt4/pyqtconfig.py

which seems to imply that the module is there, but it is not recognized. What can I do? (I've lost half a day on this...)